# How to check if key exists in multidimensional dictionary?

Tags: python

```
array = {"key1":{"key2":"value"}}

if 'key1' in array:
    if 'key2' in array['key1']:
        print(array['key1']['key2'])
    else
        print(0)
```

In php it is like this `if(isset(array[key1][key2]))`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: you should edit a bit your question... for example, what is your desired output? I guess your code works...so what do you mean by "how check key"? ...use recursion?

Comment: i need to check if exist array[key1][key2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `in` to the dict value of `array['key1']`

```
if 'key1' in array and 'key2' in array['key1']:
```

This is equivalent to the explicit form:

```
if 'key1' in array.keys() and 'key2' in array['key1'].keys():
```

A side note, if you're only interested in the value, you might want to look at [dict.get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) which returns the value of the key if present and returns `None` if not present (unless you set the `default` argument which would be the one returned instead).

Comment: I get an error if the key1 does not exist

Comment: I updated the answer to check on both keys.

Comment: I'd just use `array.get('key1', {}).get('key2', 0)`, so the values would be looked up once

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.get()`:

```
>>> array.get("key1", {}).get("key2", 0)
```

Comment: Smart trick passing the `{}` fallback so that it always returns a dict